How can you describe this recursive series using sigma notation?
The integral $\int x^ne^x \, \mathrm{d}x$ is given, along with the solution for several values of n.

$n=1,\ e^x(x-1)$
$n=2,\ e^x(x^2-2x+2)$
$n=3,\ e^x(x^3-3x^2+6x-6)$
$n=4,\ e^x(x^4-4x^3+12x^2-24x+24)$

I am then asked to identify a pattern, and find a general solution for $\int x^ne^x \, \mathrm{d}x$, specifically, using summation notation. The pattern is easily identifiable, and a recursive formula is thus quickly found: $a_n=e^xx^n-na_{n-1}$.
Now the only issue is the converting to summation notation. I'm not too sure where to start.
I could also try converting the formula $$e^xx^n-\int x^{n-1}e^x \, \mathrm{d}x$$
But that runs into the same problem as before. I'm not too sure how to convert this to summation notation. Converting from any of these formulas to summation Notation might be completely off the mark, as this is from a Calculus 2 course, but I don't see any other viable strategies.
(For further clarification, the instructions were: "Based on the patterns [above] make a conjecture as to the value of the integral when $n$ is a positive integer. Consider using summation notation.")

Something that might help you is noticing that $6 \cdot 5 \cdot 4 = 6!/3!$. More specifically, you might want to include a term of the form $n!/k!$ in your sum.

The coefficients without alternating signs is just OEIS sequence A008279.

Preliminary note.
In fact, you needn't recognize a pattern by inspection in order to obtain the relation $a_n = x^ne^x - na_{n-1}$, because it can be done by integrating $a_n = \int x^ne^x \,\mathrm{d}x$ by parts once.
Main result.
Divide the recurrence relation by $(-1)^nn!$ and define $b_n = \frac{a_n}{(-1)^nn!}$ in order to get $b_n-b_{n-1} = e^x\frac{x^n}{(-1)^nn!}$, which telescopes as
$$
b_n-b_0 = \sum_{k=1}^n (b_k-b_{k-1}) = e^x\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{x^k}{(-1)^kk!},
$$
hence finally
$$
a_n = (-1)^nn!\left(a_0 + e^x\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{x^k}{(-1)^kk!}\right) 
    = e^x\sum_{k=0}^n \frac{(-1)^nn!}{(-1)^kk!}x^k,
$$
letting aside the arbitrary constant of integration. Note that the initial term, namely $a_0 = e^x$, has been included inside the sum as the case $k = 0$.

If we let
$$
I_n = \int x^n e^x \, \mathrm{d}x
$$
then you should have observed that
$$
I_n = x^n e^x -n I_{n-1}
$$
(Double-check your integration-by-parts, you forgot the factor of $n$.) Try "unraveling" this recursion back to $I_1$ or $I_0$. For instance,
$$\begin{align*}
I_3
&= x^3 e^x - 3I_2 \\
&= x^3 e^x - 3\Big( x^2 e^x - 2I_1 \Big) \\
&= x^3 e^x - 3 \Big( x^2 e^x - 2\Big( xe^x - I_0 \Big) \Big)
\end{align*}$$
$I_0$ is something you should be able to find, and then you can deal with all of the distribution. You should also notice how $e^x$ should factor out of everything very cleanly, and hopefully a pattern should be made clear. Even moreso if you don't actually group together the constants, e.g. in the sense the above could be written as
$$
I_3 =  x^3 e^x + (-3) x^2 e^x + (-3)(-2) xe^x + (-3)(-2)(-1) I_0
$$
Now try to do this for the general $I_n$ case!
